# Deleting symbols in QGIS symbol selector?

Tags: qgis, symbology, delete

How do I delete symbols in the symbol selector QGIS?

I am trying to clear out a few old symbols from the library and was wondering how id do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Choose Style Manager from the Settings menu. You can then use the " - " symbol on the right. For more details, see [Symbol Library](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/style_library.html).

[image]